# ignore interface abstract method to be optimized in Proguard?

Tags: java, android, maven, proguard

I have a class CustomListener which is Mentioned like below :

```
public interface CustomListener{
     public abstract void abd(ArrayList<customObject> list);
}
```

this class is in my library and when I built it with maven and Proguard this method gets optimized to
generic ArrayList type as below. How can I skip proguard doing that?

```
public interface CustomListener{
     public abstract void abd(ArrayList list);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Anyway, it might not be proguard doing that, but java itself. Proguard operates on the java compiled code, and that does not have the type information anymore, it's just used for compile time error checking and to eliminate casting.

Comment: Because Its a callback method which is called when my download is sucessfull. normal jar file without proguard has ArrayList<customObject> in my method. so I believe its issue of proguard.

Comment: You response does not really answer my question. Anyway, here's a nice explanation of what happens: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens
And you are right, it's probably proguard, but I still don't see why you need that to be kept. Does it cause an error?

Comment: thanks a lot. I replaced my method parameter to CustomObject[] instead of arraylist and it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java compiler stores generic signatures in `Signature` attributes. The Java virtual machine ignores these attributes (erasure), so ProGuard removes them by default. You can keep them if necessary, e.g. for reflection or for processing libraries:

```
-keepattributes Signature
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... worked for me... also for all the methods which are throwing exceptions.. they are getting modified and never asked me to put try catch when it is suppposed to.. can you let me know how can i keep throws in method signature too.. in my jar file?

Comment: I found it.. thanks... its -keepattributes Exceptions